# Get Number of Characters with Space from Word Document

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word, office-interop

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word to count number of characters with space but when i am using inbuilt function i.e count it gives me more count then viewing manually from word document.

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
 doc = word.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
                ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,
                ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,
                ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,ref missing,
                ref missing,ref missing,ref missing);                
            doc.Activate();
            double count = doc.Content.Characters.Count;
```

so, is this any method which can directly give characters with space?

Comment: How about `double totcount = doc.Content.Characters.Count + doc.Words.Count`

Comment: he want character number, not character number + words number

Comment: yes, i want only count of characters with space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = doc.Content; 
rng.Select(); 
int nb = rng.ComputeStatistics(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticCharactersWithSpaces);
```

Comment: still give more characters from word document